# I disabled Meteor websockets and now it's not reverting back

Tags: meteor, websocket, sockjs

I’ve disabled websockets changing the environment variable (as explained here: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Websockets ) but since this has enabled `sockjs` I wasn’t able to reverse it back yet, how can I do this?

I’m not sure if it’s a bug or something I missed.

I've tried `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=0` and `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS="FALSE"` and `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=FALSE` but I keep seeing sockjs in action as if the value was 1.

I happen to have the same app in another server where I didn't disable websockets and I can confirm that sockjs is definitely on use only on the server where I've disabled websockets on the first time.

Comment: by the way: I'm using Meteor 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding this condition in the Javascript server side: `process.env.DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS = false;`